# how to implement methods in a test class?

Tags: java, class, test-class

I made this class but I cannot find a way to make the test class and implement the methods I used.

```
public class Battery
{      
       private float fullCharge = 3000;
       private float batteryCapacity;
       public Battery (float capacity)
       {
            if(capacity >0) 
            batteryCapacity = capacity;
            fullCharge = capacity;          
       }  
       public void drain (float amount)
      {
             batteryCapacity = batteryCapacity -= amount;
       }
       public void charge (float amount)
       {
             batteryCapacity = fullCharge;
       }
       public float getRemainingCapacity()
       {
             return batteryCapacity;
       }
}
```

Comment: I guess this is java instead of javascript.

Comment: wrong tag and also format your code please.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) so far?  What problem(s) are you having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method implementations are almost correct. But there are a few minor errors.

First I guess when you say:

```
if(capacity >0)
batteryCapacity = capacity;
fullCharge = capacity;
```

You actually mean:

```
if(capacity >0) {
    batteryCapacity = capacity;
    fullCharge = capacity;
}
```

In your drain method, you decresed the `batteryCapacity` wrongly. It's just:

```
batteryLeft -= amount;
```

In your `charge` method, you didn't use the paramter `amount` so I think it's better to delete taht paramter. Alternatively, You can add the amount to `batteryCapacity` like this

```
batteryCapacity += amount;
```

I hope this helps. By the way I think you should name your `batteryCapcity` variable to something like `batteryLeft` to increase clarity.